# Steam won't run ubuntu 14.04 libc.so.6

Tags: 14.04, steam, 32-bit

Steam worked perfectly until a few weeks ago. After an upgrade whenever I want to run steam I get this error:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6
```

I installed those libraries and have tried all other solutions I found but none worked...

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Did you install the 32bit versions of the libaries, and what error output do you get in terminal?

Comment: the same Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6